# material ui, redux optionally connected generic higher order (HOC) react component typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, material-ui

I am trying to create a some HOC for some of the components I have. and it need to be very generic/versatile for different scenarios. e.g. `withData` could be used in multiple different components.

currently example of connected/withStyles component.

```
export const ConnectedComponentWithStyles = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withStyles(useStyles)(MyComponent));
```

- The HOCs I am creating could be both class component as well as
  functional component.
- The component may or may not have `withStyles` HOC from material ui.
- The component may or may not have `connect` from Redux.
- The component may or may not have `withRoute` from `react-router-dom`

I could find solutions separately for `material-ui` or `redux` or without any of these but not for different combined scenarios.

e.g. withStyles only

```
  type WrapperProps = WithStyles<typeof styles>;

  const withStyles = <P extends {}>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) => {
    type Props = P & WrapperProps;

    return (props: Props) => {
      return (
          <Component {...props} />
      );
    };
  };
```

or simple component

```
export const withData = function<P extends any>(
    WrappedComponent: new () => React.Component<P, any>
) {
    return class MyHOC extends React.Component<P, any> {
        render() {
            return (
                <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

example error

```
Argument of type 'ComponentType<Pick<any, string | number | symbol> & StyledComponentProps<"title" | "toolbar" | "root" | "toolbarIcon" | "appBar" | "appBarShift" | "menuButton" | "menuButtonHidden" | "appBarSpacer">>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => Component<Pick<any, string | number | symbol> & StyledComponentProps<"title" | "toolbar" | "root" | "toolbarIcon" | "appBar" | "appBarShift" | "menuButton" | "menuButtonHidden" | "appBarSpacer">, any, any>'.
  Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<any, string | number | symbol> & StyledComponentProps<"title" | "toolbar" | "root" | "toolbarIcon" | "appBar" | "appBarShift" | "menuButton" | "menuButtonHidden" | "appBarSpacer">, any>' is not assignable to type 'new () => Component<Pick<any, string | number | symbol> & StyledComponentProps<"title" | "toolbar" | "root" | "toolbarIcon" | "appBar" | "appBarShift" | "menuButton" | "menuButtonHidden" | "appBarSpacer">, any, any>'.  TS2345
```

Comment: Replace `new () => React.Component<P, any>` with `React.ComponentType<P>`

Comment: If you are adding of removing props in the HOC then your returned component type needs to change accordingly.  Though in the examples here there is no change to `P`